# What happens when a mantra deeksha given is totally forgotten or not followed ? Can it be restarted again?

Tags: scripture, vedas, practice

Can a mantra deeksha given , which was stopped abruptly be restarted again ? Are there any Do's and Dont's to do so ?

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism SE! We do not entertain personal advice questions. Kindly remove those part and it should be fine. :)

Comment: Sure it has been taken out

Comment: Thank you :) BTW While you're exploring main site, feel free to ping in chatroom if you need help: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15189/hinduism [For talking in chat you would need at least 20 rep.]

Comment: Ask the Guru who gave it.

Answer (score 3):

I have been told by the Gurus that forgetting the Guru given mantra is the worst possible thing that can happen to the disciple (I think it's extremely rare that it actually happens). Abandoning the mantra (i.e. if you have not "followed" the mantra diksha) is also not good at all.

Lord Shiva warns in this regard as follows:

> mantra-tyAgAd-bhaven-mrityu-guru-tyAgAd-daridratA |
> guru-mantra-parityAgAd-rauravam narakam vrajet ||
>
> Abandoning the mantra results in death; abandoning the Guru results in
> poverty. And, by abandoning both one goes to a hell called Raurava.
>
> **KulArnava Tantram 12.52**

I not trying to frighten you neither you have to take this warning literally. Instead it should be interpreted as that it's not a good thing at all to completely stop practicing the mantra your Guru has given you.

If you can remember the mantra now, you can start practicing it again. If you can't do that then in that situation the best person to guide you further is your Guru himself.

Comment: @Anonrev if you’re satisfied with this answer, please do accept it by clicking the tick ( ✔️) below the voting arrows on the answer. That’s how people know this is the most appropriate answer. Also if you do like it, irrespective of whether you accept it, please do contribute an upvote as a token of appreciation. Thanks :)